# Writing or Getting to redis cluster is too slow

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

my config option

```
> Array ( [exceptions] => 1 [prefix] => sjzj: [cluster] => redis
> [parameters] => Array ( [database] => 0 [password] =>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ) )
> 
> nodes option Array ( [0] => tcp://10.103.16.12:6379 [1] =>
> tcp://10.103.0.10:6379 [2] => tcp://10.103.12.11:6379 [3] =>
> tcp://10.103.6.12:6379 [4] => tcp://10.103.12.90:6379 [5] =>
> tcp://10.103.100.156:6379 )
```

Note: The above configuration values have been modified, not the real values

6 external servers, three masters and three slaves

I tried to set 2000 data in a loop, the whole process was very long, resulting in php timeout

```
> for ($i=0; $i<2000; $i++){
>       $redis->set("a{$i}", $i) }
```

Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I really don’t know what to do, please give pointers, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Redis Slow log

https://redis.io/commands/slowlog

OR

Try checking latency to the Redis instances

https://redis.io/topics/latency